# I do not get any indication that the appropriate method has fired (I have a NSLog in drawRect)

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, storyboard

In my storyboard, I have a view controller with a custom View Controller class - BulbViewController. This has a sub-view, which I have implemented by dragging in a view on the Storyboard. What I need to do is get that View object so I can use the `drawRect` method.

I have dragged an outlet from my storyboard to the BulbViewController.h file as such:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet BulbView *theBulbView;
```

However, if I try to reference this in the .m file, doing:

```
@synthesize theBulbView;

...

- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [theBulbView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

I do not get any indication that the appropriate method has fired (I have a `NSLog` in `drawRect`). I'm not quite sure why this is. Reading up on the issue, it seems I may have to do something with child views? Perhaps like this in BulbViewController.m:

```
[self.view addSubView:theBulbView];
```

However I'm not quite sure where to go from there. Any and all help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the view that you dragged out in the storyboard is an instance of the custom UIView subclass you wrote.  Select the view, go into the identity inspector and make sure you type in the name of your UIView subclass (eg. BulbView)

Comment: Double checked this - the Custom Class defined in the Identity Inspector is BulbView

Comment: when I do what you said, the log prints to the console.  could you upload to github or screenshot?

Comment: Is the adding to child view necessary? I will delete everything and re-try it, if that doesn't work I'll pastebin some code. Thank you!

Comment: Ah! Magically works. Just removed the view and put it back in - was probably doing something wrong. Many thanks!